# Return File to client side without save in sever side which download from GCP cloud storage

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm Working with Flask and React Development tasks, so I need to serve files from the flask backend to react client side which is download from GCP Cloud Storage from Flask Backend.

So my Current Approach is as bellow.

```
@app.route('/api/download-file', methods=['GET'])
@token_required
def download_blob():
    """Downloads a blob."""

    file_name = request.args.get('file_name')
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(app.config.get('CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET'))
    blob = bucket.blob(file_name)
    print(blob.exists())
    blob.download_to_filename(file_name)
    return send_file("./" + file_name, as_attachment=True, mimetype="application/vnd.ms-excel")
```

so my problem is now all files downloaded from flask are saved in the server folder and after the return statement, I can't execute lines to delete that file.

I couldn't find any solution for the return file without saving inside server

Comment: Serve the file from memory if small small enough. 1) blob.download_as_string() 2) Create a ByteIO object (mem) and copy in the string. 3) Serve the file from memory **return send_file(mem, as_attachment=True, mimetype="application/vnd.ms-excel")** 4) Now you do not need to delete the temporary file. 5) **send_file()** might be able to accept a string, I did not verify which means skipping the ByteIO object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on JohnHanley's comments able to achieve the goal with the below code. from that way can serve any files without concern about the content type

```
@app.route('/api/download-file', methods=['GET'])
@token_required
def download_blob():
    """Downloads a blob."""

    file_name = "dir/" + request.args.get('file_name')
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(app.config.get('CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET'))
    blob = bucket.get_blob(file_name)
    content_type = None
    try:
        content_type = blob.content_type
    except:
        pass
    file = blob.download_as_string()
    print(type(file), "downloaded type")
    return Response(file,  mimetype=content_type)
```

Comment: wait, ain't we still download the file using "download_as_string" here?